# Is there a way for a JQuery ajax success function to access the object it's contained in?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have javascript like this:

```
function Cat() { 

  this.meow = function() { // meow };

  $.ajax( do AJAX call, success: this.meow(); );

}

var TopCat = new Cat();
```

This does not work because 'this' makes no sense in the context of the success function. Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `context` parameter to the `ajax` method.
It allows you to set the context in which all callbacks will be called.

```
function Cat() { 
    this.meow = function() { // meow };
    $.ajax({
        context: this, 
        success: function() { this.meow(); } 
    });    
}
```

Comment: thanks. though I needed to do `success: function() {this.context.meow();}`

Comment: NB: if setting `context: this` you can also just write `success: this.meow` - no need for the extra function wrapper.