# jQuery ajax callback member of class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way for a JQuery ajax success function to access the object it’s contained in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378622/is-there-a-way-for-a-jquery-ajax-success-function-to-access-the-object-its-cont)

I have some code like that

```
myClass.prototype.doStuff = function(){

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#form').attr('action'),
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: this.callback
  });
};

myClass.prototype.callback = function(data){
   if(this.someFlag){
     //do some stuff  
   }

};
```

In this case I supposed `this` to be the instance of myClass, but it isn't actually. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass [`context: this`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as an ajax option.

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#form').attr('action'),
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    context: this,
    success: this.callback
});
```