# Accessing `this` in Ajax callback, all within an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I'm dealing with a problem about an Ajax callback inside of an Object.
Please consider this code :

```
Search.prototype =
{
    ask : function( query )
    {
        // Display loader
        $('.loader').show();

        $.ajax({
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'http://api.deezer.com/search/track/',
            data : {
                output : 'jsonp',
                q : query
            }
        }).done(function(res) {

            this.loadResults( res );
            // [Error] Object success has no method 'loadResult'

        });
    },

    loadResults : function (res)
    {
        // Hide loader
        $('.loader').hide();

        console.log( res );

        // doing some stuff
        // ...
    }
}

var search = new Search();
search.ask( 'eminem' );
```

I get an error `Object success has no method loadResult` , which makes sense as the callback is part of an anonymous jQuery function.

But how to get my initial object instance ?

I've been trying with a var that = this; before the Ajax call, but I't won't works for the same reasons.

I don't know if it's possible to do this or if the problem comes from my code global organization. Feel free to advise me about the best practices :)

Thanks by advance.

### [Update (solved)]

I obfuscated some things in my code which I though it was unnecessary to post here, but I finally found out the problem a little bit earlier in my code.
Sorry about that.

Here's my full code, which is now working :

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    var Search = function()
    {
        this._keyDownTimer = 0;
        this._searchDelay = 1000; // ms
    };

    Search.prototype =
    {
        // The init function that I though it was unnecessary to post here. Sorry :/
        init : function()
        {
            $('#q').on('keydown', (function(evt) {

                clearTimeout( this._keyDownTimer );

                this._keyDownTimer = setTimeout( (function() {

                    this.ask( $('#q').val() );

                }).bind( this ), this._searchDelay); /* <-- Here's the solution.
                                                        I forgot to bind `this`
                                                        to the timeout callback function,
                                                        so the `this` under all of my code
                                                        was referring to the anonymous function
                                                        of this callback. */

            }).bind( this ));
        },

        ask : function( query )
        {
            // Display loader
            $('.loader').show();

            console.log(this); // Now `this` refers to my object :)

            var req = $.ajax({
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'http://api.deezer.com/search/track/',
                context : this,
                data : {
                    output : 'jsonp',
                    q : query
                }
            });

            req.done(function(res) {
                this.loadResults(res);
            });
        },

        loadResults : function (res)
        {
            // Hide loader
            $('.loader').hide();

            // doing some stuff
            // ...
        }
    };

    return new Search;

});
```

Thanks for your replies, it really helped.

Pb solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax callback memeber of class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863333/jquery-ajax-callback-memeber-of-class)

Comment: when you did `var that = this` did you also change `this.loadResults()` to `that.loadResults()` ?

Comment: Matt : yep I guess it's the same problem.
Alnitak : I did before posting here, it doesn't change anything as I think `var that` scope is defined in the scope of the .search method, and when the callback is fired, `var that` doesn't exists anymore.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

You can set the `context` setting for the ajax options:

#### [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `context` setting

```
$.ajax({
    context: this
```

#### [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
    .done(function (res) {

    }.bind(this));
```

However, this is not as widely supported as...

#### [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Created for this purpose.

```
    .done($.proxy(function (res) {

    }, this);
```

#### Assigning this to another value

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
/* snip */
.done(function (res) {
    self.loadResults(res);
```

This is commonly done in JavaScript to give access to `this` in lower scopes.

#### Arrow functions with lexical binding

```
$.ajax({
/* snip */
.then(res => this.loadResults(res));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `context` object here like:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://api.deezer.com/search/track/',
    context: this,
    ...
}).done(function (res) {
    this.loadResults( res );
});
```

Comment: also works with `.error(function (res) {...}` and can be chained to the call

Comment: `this.loadResults( res )` didn't work in my case, but worked when omitting "this", i.e. should be `loadResults( res )`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ES5 [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function to set `this` correctly:

```
$.ajax(...).done(this.loadResults.bind(this));
```

(use the shim at the above link, or the jQuery `$.proxy` equivalent on older browsers).

Alternatively, add `context: this` to the `$.ajax` options:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    context: this
}).done(this.loadResults);
```

Note that in either case you will override jQuery's default behaviour of passing the ajax option object in `this`.

p.s. it's also good practise to `return` the result of the `$.ajax()` chain so that the user of your object can chain additional callbacks (e.g. a `.fail` handler) to it.

Comment: I've tried with context: this, with binding `this` to the callback function (anonymous and directly on `this.loadResults`) but I still get the initial error :(

Comment: @jmpp indeed, on seeing your update `this` must (of course) already hold the correct value in the first place for any of the above methods to work.