# Sub functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Need advice writing a code in JS. Here's my code:

```
function Book(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // Some vars need to be downloaded
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/books.php"
    }).done(function( res ) {
        this.price = this.analyze(res); // <--WRONG
        return this;
    });
}

Book.prototype.analyze = function(res){
    var output = 50 * res;
    // do something
    return output;
}
```

Check the marked line. what would be the best way to achieve what I was trying to do there?

Comment: even then it won't work as `this` on the WRONG line relates to the function

Comment: Additionally, depending if the operation in GetPrice takes long, you should probably use a callback instead of setting a variable to the result of a function.

Comment: You could add `var myBook = this;` at the top of your Constructor function and then run that line using `myBook.price = myBook.getPrice()` since myBook would be part of the scope, but `this` changes with scope. (You would still need `getPrice` in the prototype)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u8bk3z1f/1/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274673/accessing-this-in-ajax-callback-all-within-an-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the $.ajax() there is a parameter 'context' . You can use it. So your code will be

```
function Book(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // Some vars need to be downloaded
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/books.php"
    }).done(function( res ) {
        this.price = this.analyze(res); // <-- not wrong any more
        return this;
    });
}
```

The problem in your code is that 'this' in your function doesn't refer to the outer class. You can change your code in two ways.

1) you can assign outer context of the object to some variable and use it in your function. i.e.

```
function Book(name) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    // Some vars need to be downloaded
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/books.php"
    }).done(function( res ) {
        self.price = self.analyze(); // <--not wrong any more
        return self;
    });
}
```

2) Another option is to make your function run on proper context using, for example $.proxy()

```
function Book(name) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    // Some vars need to be downloaded
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/books.php"
    }).done($.proxy(function( res ) {
        this.price = this.analyze(); // <--not wrong any more
        return this;
    }, self));
}
```

Comment: I somehow thought there's another way of doing this except defining "this" as a variable in the "parent" function. but well, i guess there isn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Before the `$.ajax` line, put `var that=this;`.  Then change your `<--WRONG` line to `return that.getPrice();`.