# passing multiple id into one ajax function

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I want to run the same js ajax function on multiples id, so I could return the specific information from my database. Here it did run through "id="test" but it returns them to all of it. How do I make them return to its own

"id"

html

```
       <div>
           <p  class="postbutton" id="test_1" > </p> \\supposed to return 1, but it returns 3//
           <p  class="postbutton" id="test_2" > </p> \\supposed to return 2, but it returns 3//
           <p  class="postbutton" id="test_3" > </p> \\supposed to return 3, but it returns 3//
       </div>
```

my scripting function

```
$(".postbutton").each(function () {
                        x = $(this).prop('id').replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') // converting it to a set of ID to be passed to my controller

                            $.ajax({
                                /* the route pointing to the post function */
                                url: '/postajax',
                                type: 'POST',
                                /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller, Laravel stuff */
                                data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message: x},
                                dataType: 'JSON',
                                /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                                success: function (data)
                                    {
                                        $(" p[id^='test']").html(data.msg);
                                    }
                                 });
                              });
```

Comment: By no means a jquery expert, but doesn't `id^='test'` mean all id's starting with test?

Comment: Did you console.log x to check what you are actually sending?

Comment: yup it does mean all id's starting with test.

Comment: i did check the console.log. and it does pass the  1,2,3 which what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).html()` otherwise, for each ajax call, `$(" p[id^='test']").html(data.msg)` will be call even the last ajax call. So the last call has 3 as answer. So it updates the two first ajax call.

```
$(".postbutton").each(function () {
                        var context = this
                        x = $(context).prop('id').replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') // converting it to a set of ID to be passed to my controller

                            $.ajax({
                                /* the route pointing to the post function */
                                url: '/postajax',
                                type: 'POST',
                                /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller, Laravel stuff */
                                data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message: x},
                                dataType: 'JSON',
                                /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                                success: function (data)
                                    {
                                        $(context).html(data.msg);
                                    }
                                 });
                              });
```

Comment: `$(this)` is **not** the same as the `$('.potbutton')` within your ajax function! You can either set the `context` of your ajax function or save this into another variable, visible to the scope of your ajax callback. Here is a detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274673/accessing-this-in-ajax-callback-all-within-an-object)

Comment: Great ! @zul Dont forgot to mark answer as resolved !

Answer (score 0):

Since ID is attribute which wont be changes in your case - try replace `.prop` with `.attr()` to get the value of ID.

Also matching that you inside success function will return all possible matches - in this case 3

Also it will be good if you use already founded ID for matching element in success function like

```
$(`#test_${x}`).html(data.msg);
```

Comment: .prop and attr() both did the job. But your $(`#test_${x}`).html(data.msg); does somewhat give me the idea where I should be looking to change, thanks!

Comment: They are not the same, just in your case they might be the same, but still it is better to use appropriate one  :)

Answer (score -1):

**First to store your all id in array.
after pass this array in your ajax function.
like this:-**

```
           var id_list=[];
            $(".postbutton").each(function () {
                        x = $(this).prop('id').replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') // converting it to a set of ID to be passed to my controller
                        id_list.push(x);
             });
            $.ajax({
                /* the route pointing to the post function */
                url: '/postajax',
                type: 'POST',
                /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller, Laravel stuff */
                data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message: id_list},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                success: function (data)
                    {
                        $(" p[id^='test']").html(data.msg);
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: but how do I sort and pass the array back to the view?